# SSRS expression giving #Error when SUM and IIF

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services, microsoft-dynamics

I am trying to create a query to SUM based on the `'TypeName'` and `'ReleaseDate'`.

I have gotten the `TypeName = Base` part of the query to work on its own. However, I am trying to add another `IIF` statement to check the `ReleaseDate`. When running this query I get an `#Error` in its place.

```
=Sum(Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.IIf(Fields!TypeName.Value = "Base", 1, 0) (Fields!ReleaseDate.Value = (DateAdd("d",-1,Today))), "DataSet1")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to SUM the number of records that have a Type of Base and a Release Date of Yesterday, you can use an AND in the IIF to use both conditions.

```
=Sum(IIF(Fields!TypeName.Value = "Base" AND Fields!ReleaseDate.Value = DateAdd("d",-1,Today), 1, 0), "DataSet1")
```

Another way would be to nest an IIF inside another IIF, but your logic doesn't really need it:

```
=Sum(IIf(Fields!TypeName.Value = "Base", IIF(Fields!ReleaseDate.Value = DateAdd("d",-1,Today), 1, 0), 0), "DataSet1")
```